# Has anyone created a Shadow DOM that stops stylesheets from bleeding/leaking out of a Shadow DOM in IE 11 or Edge?

Tags: css, web-component, shadow-dom

I need a web component that will not allow styles to bleed out of the Shadow DOM in IE 11 or Edge.  Inline styles will work, but I need to use stylesheets.

I've tried everything including standard web components, polymer/LiteElement, react-shadow-dom-component and plain old JS.  The code I'm attaching is very basic. This example doesn't use stylesheets, and it still bleeds over.  I've tried multiple polyfills.  I've also tried loader with defer and async.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>hello-world</title>

<!-- Imports polyfill -->
<!--<script src="../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="/node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents- 
bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@^2/"> 
</script>

<!--<script src="node_modules/custom-elements-es5-adapter/custom- 
elements-es5-adapter.js"></script>-->
<!-- Imports custom element -->
<!--<link rel="import" href="hello-world.html">-->
<!--<script src="shadowComponent.js"></script>-->
<style>

    .text {
        color: red;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="text">I should be red.</div>

<div id="myText"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var element = document.getElementById('myText');
    var styles = '.text{color: blue; }';

    var content = 'I should be blue.';

    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(styles));

    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.className = 'text';
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));

    var shadowRootContainer = element.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    var innerContainer = document.createElement('div');
    shadowRootContainer.appendChild(innerContainer);

    var shadowRoot = innerContainer.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

    shadowRoot.appendChild(style);
    shadowRoot.appendChild(p);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

There is a nested Shadow DOM in this example because I was at my wits end and decided to throw some code at the wall to see if anything would stick.  I know that order matters in styles.  I expect that with the polyfills this should work.  It works in Chrome (obviously) FF, and Opera.  I have more complex examples if necessary.  Again any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no shadowDOM in IE11 or Edge (pre-chromium). So there is no built-in way to prevent shadowDOM penetration.

If you use something like BEM or some other way of name-spacing your CSS selectors you can limit the penetration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Intervalia.  I've come to the same conclusion and recommended name-spacing as well to my manager.  I'm going to leave this unsolved for a bit in the hopes that maybe someone has something.  If not  I'll mark your answer as accepted.  Thanks again.

Comment: If I am writing a generic component that needs to work on IE then I do not use shadow DOM. If I know the component will only be used on the latest browsers then i use shadow DOM if it makes sense. But I do not always use it.

Comment: We unfortunately have to support IE 11 and Edge.  We have several ideas for workarounds.  As you mentioned, name-spacing.  We're also considering simply mangling the code in the shadow DOM.  I'd personally like to fork the webcomponents.js polyfill repo and see if it can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can mostly emulate ShadowDOM scoped CSS with the [ShadyCSS](https://github.com/webcomponents/polyfills/tree/master/packages/shadycss) component of the [webcopmonentsjs](https://github.com/webcomponents/polyfills/tree/master/packages/webcomponentsjs) polyfill. There are some [limitations](https://github.com/webcomponents/polyfills/tree/master/packages/shadycss#limitations) and it will only contain CSS within the component, it won't prevent external styles from leaking in.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  If you run that code above the style from the second style will leak out and bleed over into the the text in the div above it for MS browsers using the polyfills.  If you use stylesheets you can create two shadow doms with different shadow hosts and the second style sheet classes will take precedence over the first with the polyfills in IE 11 and Edge.

Comment: Taking a another look at ShadyCSS I think it currently only supports scoped styles within a custom element. So if you were to define a custom element  and used the ShadyCSS API inside the style would behave correctly.